# Collection of Lines

Tags: wpf, collections, line

I have to draw a collection of lines in WPF with different colors. Each color part is a line.

For Example we have a line starting from (0,0) to (10,0) on xaxis.

I want red color from (0,0) to (3,0) and green from (3,0) to (7,0) and yellow from (7,0) to (10,0).

I want to treat this whole thing as a single line . I have one way that is drawing different lines from those points and giving different strokes for each line. Is there something in WPF for collection of lines with different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What classes do you use? If you can apply a brush to the line you can create a [`LinearGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush.aspx) which looks like that. You will need stops on the same offset with different colours to get a hard change.

e.g.

```
<Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="100" Y2="0" StrokeThickness="5">
    <Line.Stroke>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Red"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Yellow"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="Yellow"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="Green"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Line.Stroke>
</Line>
```

Comment: How if I want to do this on a graph line, which has thousands of points plotted on a  scale?

Comment: @user679530: If the graph line accepts a brush like this there should be no difference at all.